# How many Y shapes can you fit on the plane?

Tags: general-topology

You can only fit at most countably many disjoint open discs on the plane: for any collection of disjoint open discs, it is possible to pick a single rational coordinate contained in each disc, and since the discs are disjoint no two discs will be assigned the same coordinate.

Say that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a Y shape iff it is homeomorphic to $\{(x,y) \mid x\in [-1,1]$ and $y=0$ or $x=0$ and $y\in [0,1]\}$. A slightly harder version of the above question: how many disjoint Y shapes can you fit on a plane?

Comment: Your definition of Y shape is actually a rectangle.

Comment: Fixed -- thanks!

Comment: So those Y shapes are rather T shaped?=)

Comment: See this link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27244/how-many-tacks-fit-in-the-plane

Comment: Up to now every 'tiling' I was able to come up with ended up using an area of $0.5+\epsilon$ per Y/T-shape. Is it possible to beat that?

Comment: @flawr: are you assuming that the Y-shapes have to be the same size? Being homeomorphic to the shape I defined doesn't require this: you can make Y shapes arbitrarily small.

Comment: Yes I assumed that - and I admit that I know nothing about topology=) (But it rather looked like a fun problem.) In this case I really didn't understand the problem, but do you know something about fitting as many of these in the plane when they have to have the same size?

Comment: I can think of several ways of defining the "size" of a Y shape. Perhaps it would be better to just focus on shapes that are isometric to the T shape I described, and to ask how many you can fit inside a fixed area? Interesting question!